# Restream a stream with VLC in real-time

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, vlc

How do I accomplish real-time video re-streaming with VLC (cli on linux) to an `m3u8` playlist?
I currently have a piece of code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
["cvlc","-v",url,"--drop-late-frames","--skip-frames","--sout","#std{access=livehttp{seglen=1,delsegs=false,numsegs=5, index=/var/www/x/test.m3u8, index-url=http://hello.com/_x/test-########.ts}, mux=ts{use-key-frames},  dst=/var/www/xxx/test-########.ts}}"
```

The code above for some reason waits 3-10 seconds to generate new .ts files - that should be done in real-time. What command line arguments should I use to correct that problem?

Answer (score 0):

m3u8 is a fragmented format. It means the manifest can not be updated until the fragment is complete (no partial fragments) Because we can not time travel, we must wait for all the frames of the fragment. 3 seconds in your case.

Comment: ffmpeg can accomplish this, so vlc should also be able to do this. This command does what I need: ["ffmpeg","-fflags","nobuffer","-re","-i",url,"-codec","copy","-map","0","-f","segment","-segment_time","2","-hls_list_size","5","-hls_wrap","5","-segment_list_type","m3u8","-segment_format","mpeg_ts","-segment_list","/var/www/x/test.m3u8","-segment_list_flags","+live","/var/www/x/test%03d.ts"]. I just need to do this with vlc.

Comment: The m3u8 updated ever X seconds, ever the segment is complete.  So you want the ts to slowly grow in real time, instead of flushing entire segment at once?

Comment: It could grow in real time (would be great to see if anything happens) - but not seeing it grow is not the problem. With vlc I should be getting new .ts files every X seconds (or every 1 second with the command above), but now I am getting a bunch of files and they are made every 3 to 10 seconds. I would be happy if they would be created one by one every 1 second.